# How to call a method in one class from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have `insertintodatabase{}` method in `sqAppDelegate` file.

Now , I want to call this method from my rootViewcontroller.m class.
How can i do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `insertintodatabase{}`?  That isn't a method declaration.  Is it a class method?  an instance method?  Classes should also start with capital letters.

Comment: sqAppDelegate is ur Delegate file or class file for the database methods?

Comment: i write the code for class method. i feel that sqAppDelegate is ur class file so. if its ur Delegateclass then Jhaliya answer is correct.

Comment: .... Who have given my answer down vote  :)

Comment: i have two files sqAppDelegate.m and RootViewController.m... i have a method inserintodatabase{} in sqAppDelegate.m. i want to call this from RootViewController.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code to access your sqAppDelegate object ...

Put the below code in any function of your `RootViewController` where you want to invoke `sqAppDelegate` method  ...

Let's suppose, tha function name is `myRootViewControllerFunctionToInvokeDelegateMethod`

```
-(void) myRootViewControllerFunctionToInvokeDelegateMethod
{
      sqAppDelegate* mydel = (sqAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      //And then invoke the function ....
      [mydel insertintodatabase];
}
```